# mongodb aggregation join even when first stage produces no results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find a way to fake the success of one aggregation stage before the next stage runs.

1. I am using $match to filter a user collection by `id`. This can
   have no results.
2. I want to use $lookup to join with another
   collection on that same `id`. This stage should produce results even when
   the previous stage returned no results.

**The problem is that $lookup only produces results when $match produces results.**

I think I need to use $replaceRoot or $project after the initial $match so that $lookup can still reference a valid field. So far, my attempts are showing no results in the $lookup stage.

Here is my attempt using `replaceRoot`. It actually succeeds when the $match succeeds, but nothing appears when the $match returns null.

```json
[{$match: {
  "id": "id-in-users-collection"
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [
    {"id": "id-fallback"},
    "$$ROOT"
  ]}
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'memberships',
  localField: 'id',
  foreignField: 'userId',
  as: 'clubs'
}}]
```

Here is one attempt using $project. I'm sure there is a problem in the syntax below, but it actually produces results when $match produces results.

```json
[{$match: {
  "id": "id-in-user-collection"
}}, {$project: {
  "id": {
    $cond: {
      if: "$$ROOT.id",
      then: "$$ROOT.id",
      else: {$literal: {"id": "id-fallback"}}
    }
  }
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'memberships',
  localField: 'id',
  foreignField: 'userId',
  as: 'clubs'
}}]
```

**EDIT:**

Lets say I have these documents in the **Memberships** collection:

```
{"userId": "1', "clubId": "1", "status": "CREATOR"}
{"userId": "2', "clubId": "1", "status": "PENDING"}
```

I want to perform an aggregation that yields the result below, for user id=2, even if there are no documents in the **User** collection:

```js
db.users.aggregate(makePipeline(2)).toArray()
```

desired:

```json
{
  "id": "2",
  "clubs": [
    {userId: '2', clubId: '1', status: 'PENDING'}
  ]
}
```

Currently, I can ONLY get the desired result when I add a document in the **User** collection.

```json
{"id": "2"}
```

Comment: Please show us some sample documents.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit done! thanks!

Comment: can you post your user collection?

Comment: @varman its empty.